# Testing hibernate OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm running integrity tests on a Spring Boot 2.1.4 project with JUnit 4.12 and I have run into a problem running a save (Comment) endpoint test in a bidirectional relationship of type @OneToOne - @ManyToOne when I use the @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference annotations to avoid recursion.

The problem is that when I run the test it isn't converting the parent (Author class) of the relation to JSON, only the child (Comment class) is converted, but with none reference to parent.

Object of class Comment received to convert it to JSON
[image]

Result of convert the object of class Comment to JSON, where is the parent?
[image]

DDL of tables in a H2 Database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `author` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `review` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `author_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_comment_author_idx` (`author_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comment_author` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Parent entity

```
@JsonManagedReference("author_comment")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

Child entity

```
@JsonBackReference("author_comment")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
private Author author;
```

Comment: The screenshots show the value of the object and the result of convert to JSON at runtime.

Comment: I see that the `author` of the comment, doesn't have any `comments` in its list, -> the list is empty. Maybe that is the problem

Comment: The object is an instance of Comment entity